# Wrap text using input from Google Sheet (Google Apps Script)

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script that produces an automated email from cell content in a Google Sheet.  Is it possible to restrict the width of a cell's output in the email, forcing the text to wrap?  I have tried using textarea tags as follows:

```
+ <textarea rows="4" cols="20">

+ sheet.getRange(6,9,1,1).getValue()   

+ </textarea>
```

However, this simply outputs as "+ sheet.getRange(6,9,1,1).getValue() +" (i.e. it doesn't generate the cell content).

Is this possible?

Here's how I have built the script:

```
function EmailFormConfirmation() { 

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  Utilities.sleep(60000);

  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form responses");

  var lock = LockService.getPublicLock();

  lock.waitLock(60000);

  lock.releaseLock();

  var email = sheet.getRange(2,9,1,1).getValue();  

  var message = "<HTML><BODY>"

    + "<P >Hi " 

    + sheet.getRange(4,9,1,1).getValue()

    + ","

    etc.
```

EDIT  The below produces the cell content, but doesn't wrap the text.

```
var htmlMsg = "<HTML><BODY>"

    + "<textarea rows='4' cols='10'>"

    + sheet.getRange(6,9,1,1).getValue()   

    + "</textarea>"

    + "</HTML></BODY>";


    MailApp.sendEmail(email, "LMI Request", "", {htmlBody: htmlMsg});
```

Comment: Are you building this with HTMLService templating or string building?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Spencer.  I have not used templating, so I assume it's string building? (I'm a novice).  I've copied the script above.  I would like to load a more complex 'styled' template that generates the cell content but I think this is beyond my capabilities.

Comment: I'd need to look at more code, since this one is working for me. Also as good practice, you should getValue only once, and then use the Array, like this, getRange(2,9,3,1), ten for the message you'd use `email[2][0]` and for the real email `email[0][0]`.

Comment: Added example on how to do this with templates

Comment: in the last line of your edited message you have the tags reversed. The closing HTML tag should be outside of the body tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To respond to the question re: textbox, the following did as you requested

```
  var htmlMsg = "<HTML><BODY>"
  + "<textarea rows='4' cols='20'>"
  + sheet.getRange(6,9,1,1).getValue()
  + "</textarea>"
  + "</BODY></HTML>";
  GmailApp.sendEmail("m....l@gmail.com", "subject","hi" , {htmlBody: htmlMsg});
```

note how the single and double quotes are used.

Comment: Many thanks for your help Michael.  Using the quotation marks correctly as in your example, the cell content is produced in the email, but the text doesn't actually wrap.  Can you spot a mistake in the code now?

Comment: in the test I tried the text box was created in the email and wrapped as expected with the code above. When you ask, can you spot a mistake in the colde now? which code are you referring to? Do you have spaces in your output so that the output will have break points to wrap?

Comment: I see that you have edited your post with the new code. there is a problem with the last line of the message you have HTML and body reversed.  do you actually see a textarea box in your email?

Comment: Sorry for that stupid mistake, I changed it around.  However, it hasn't made any difference.  I don't see any sort of box, just the text from the cell, which doesn't wrap.

Comment: does the output text have spaces in it to be able to wrap on? Does your email client support html?

Comment: I did not realise that the text had to have spaces to wrap.  Pretty stupid.  I tried with spaces and it does indeed work, so you solved the problem and I was just stupid.  Thanks so much for your help.  Unfortunately I can't vote you up as I don't have any points.  Thanks Michael!!

Comment: Done, didn't realise I could.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can use templates to build your email responses. The documentation can be found here:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates

In code.gs

```
function myFunction(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp .....
  var value = sheet.getRange(6,9,1,1).getValue();
  var emailHtml = buildTemplate(value);
   GmailApp.sendEmail("person@example.com", "subject","Hello", {htmlBody: emailHtml});  
}

function buildTemplate(values){  
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('emailTemplate');
  template.tmpValues = values;
  return template.evaluate().getContent();
}
```

in emailTemplate.html

```
<html>
  <body>
       <textarea rows='4' cols='20'>
         <?=tmpValues?>
       </textarea>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Spencer, many thanks for this.  I will follow your example to set up a template, if I can't get it to work in the current string.  Thanks a lot.